# Get all legs when using google direction API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try and get all public transport from the Google Directions services. Starting from two different addresses.

Can I get the Status on each Router?

For example "Status Is On Time", "Status is Late"

Below is my request:

Start From: Buckingham, UK

Destination: The British Museum, Great Russell St, Bloomsbury, London WC1B 3DG, United Kingdom

Call from API Url:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&mode=transit&origin=Buckingham,+UK&destination=The+British+Museum,+Great+Russell+St,+Bloomsbury,+London+WC1B+3DG,+United+Kingdom&alternatives=true&key=YOUR_API_KEY

[image]

Thank you so much for all help.

Comment: I get multiple legs with the [first request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&mode=transit&origin=Buckingham,+UK&destination=The+British+Museum,+Great+Russell+St,+Bloomsbury,+London+WC1B+3DG,+United+Kingdom&alternatives=true&key=) (when I add a key)

Comment: Actually, when you say "legs", do you mean the "legs" array in the response?  I see multiple "steps" with different travel_modes (WALKING or TRANSIT), which is what I see on Google Maps.  Is that what you are seeing on Google Maps?

Comment: Documentation says: *There will be one leg for each stopover waypoint or destination specified. So a route with no stopover waypoints will contain one `DirectionsLeg` and a route with one stopover waypoint will contain two.* and I get only 1 leg with the first request which is expected.